# Is there an API available for using the Samsung TV network remote control feature?

Tags: java, android, samsung-mobile, television, samsung-smart-tv

I want to write an Android app which controls my Samsung TV via the wifi network. This is possible because there are apps out there that do it (including Samsung's own remote app).

Is there a Samsung API available to do this? How does the app talk to the TV?

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source project of SamyGo, and it works perfect. I am using it on my android phone and with the help of that project source, I created a little remote control with c#. You can always check their offical forum link for latest news.

http://sourceforge.net/p/samygo/code/1286/tree/

http://forum.samygo.tv/index.php

Comment: the github project seems to be offline meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be a good start (Samsung SDK for their TVs):

http://www.samsungdforum.com/Devtools/SdkDownload

Answer (score 0):

I've used this for PC based Java apps and it works well ... might be of some use:

https://github.com/mhvis/samsung-tv-control